# Use Koa to stream an ExcelJS workbook immediately to the browser

Tags: node.js, stream, koa, exceljs

What I would like is to stream my ExcelJS workbook little by little to the browser. The problem is that I'm very uncomfortable with streams.

The facts:

- I'm on Node JS v.18
- I'm using last version of ExcelJS library to generate a big Excel file (v.4)
- I'm using last version of Koa as a REST API tool (v.2)

Here's a simplified part of my code. The Excel workbook is ok. If I create a full buffer in memory and send this buffer to Koa, I can download it. But when I'm trying to stream and pass a stream to koa, things go wrong. The way of passing stream to ExcelJS is the right way, from their docs.

**EDIT**

Here's a full working work base (except for streams).

package.json

```
{
  "name": "stackoverflow-exceljs-koa",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "rekam",
  "dependencies": {
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "koa": "^2.13.4"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const app = new Koa();

const { exportExcelData } = require('./builder');

app.use(async ctx => {
  if (ctx.request.url === '/file') {
    await exportExcelData('useFile', './test.xlsx');
    ctx.body = 'Done, file saved at ' + __dirname + '/test.xlsx';
    return;
  }

  if (ctx.request.url === '/stream') {
    // const stream = new Stream();
    // ctx.body = stream;
    // await exportExcelData('useStream', stream);
    ctx.body = 'to be implemented';
    return;
  }

  ctx.body = 'Not Found';
  ctx.status = 404;
});

app.listen(8101);  
console.log('visit http://localhost:8101/file or /stream');
```

builder.js

```
const Excel = require('exceljs');

module.exports = {
  async exportExcelData(type, streamOrFilename) {
    const limit = 100;
    let offset = 0;

    const workbook = new Excel.stream.xlsx.WorkbookWriter({
      stream: type === 'useStream' ? streamOrFilename : undefined,
      filename: type === 'useFile' ? streamOrFilename : undefined,
      useSharedStrings: true,
      useStyles: true
    });

    const sheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Export');
    sheet.columns = [{
      header: 'ID',
      key: 'id'
    }];

    const build = offset => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => {
      const rows = Array.from({ length: limit }).map((_, i) => ({ id: i + offset }));
      if (offset > 10000) {
        rows.pop(); // will break while looop
      }
      rows.forEach(row => sheet.addRow(row).commit());
      return resolve(rows);
    }, 1));

    let rows;
    do {
       rows = await build(offset);
       offset += limit;
    } while (rows.length === limit);

    sheet.commit();

    await workbook.commit();

    return;
  }
};
```

usage

```
$ node index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some further tests and thanks to other related problems, I found a solution, which is this one:

```
const stream = ctx.res;
ctx.response.attachment('test.xlsx');
ctx.status = 200;
await exportExcelData('useStream', stream);
ctx.res.end();
```

Of course, you need to catch exceptions and adapt ctx status and body response. But with this code, you will have a streamed content of any GB you want.